# What's the best background wall tile for pixel art?

Tags: terraria

I'd like to paint a pixel art mural using the [Paint Roller](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Paint_Roller). I would like to use a background with the least amount of texture "noise" so the colors of the pixel art stands out the most. To illustrate, here are several pre-hardmode background tiles painted sky blue:

[image]

(cactus, dirt, mahogany, bone, mushroom, stone, wood)

Based on this limited sample, dirt walls out of everything seem to do alright:

[image]

However this is not even close to all available walls in the game. Which wall is the most plain and makes colors the most vibrant?

Comment: I think that the plainest wall you can get is dirt. Sorry. But if you're looking for a constant pattern, you can look up Disc Walls. Only these have circle shapes, not squares.

Comment: Voting to close:  This is a question about art, not gaming.  Also, it's primarily opinion based.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft by the same token you could close all [minecraft-redstone] questions because they are about programming rather than killing skeletons.

Comment: @kotekzot: [Highly relevant](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7661).  Redstone is borderline-acceptable because its knowledge is a core part of Minecraft, but even redstone questions might be closed as off-topic if they are complex enough to require significant ESE knowledge.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft perhaps if the question was about duplicating the Sistine Chapel rather than picking a block with the least amount of color variance.

Comment: I would still consider that off-topic as well, but you're free to take it up on meta.

Comment: Also, this question is totally not opinion-based and can be answered with mathematics.

Comment: 4 months later and still it has no answer... I personally think the problem isn't the walls themselves, but the contrast. The way to create more *noticeable* art is to have a color difference between the art and the frame. Before Paint, people created "pixel" art in Terraria through blocks, in open air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [Sails](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Sail), sold from the pirate.

[image: Sails]

Or possibly Boreal Wood Walls

[image: Boreal Wood Walls]

If you are not gathering mats you may want too look at Gem Walls, and Hardmode Ore Walls.

[Terraria Wiki on Walls](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wall)

Answer (score 0):

Wood has little noise. I'd suggest that.

Comment: @3ventic Noise as in "visual noise".

Answer (score 0):

Gemspark wall is known to be the flattest coloured wall in terraria. I'd check it out. It does have a very obvious downside

Comment: This answer could be improved by telling us what that obvious downside is.